# How to make a batch file wait until setup finished

Tags: batch-file, setup.exe

I tried to put this into a example.bat call= blahblah.exe call= example.bat /wait blahblah.exe

but the above does not wait, it will call the example.bat as soon as the blahblah.exe runs.

I want to start the example.bat when the WHOLE blahblah.exe has finished. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `start`. If you wanted to run `a.bat`, execute `b.exe` then run `c.bat` when it exits;

**`a.bat`**:

```
start /wait b.exe
call c.bat
```